# jQuery sortable -- enable sortable only on drag, not click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a bunch of divs which have jQuery sortable (as grid) enabled. This is all working fine, but I want to only have sortable enabled when a user drags the div - not when he clicks it. For example, these divs have scrollbars, and whenever you drag the handle, it binds the div to the mouse and forces you to sort it. How do I turn this off?

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(  "#sortable"  ).sortable({ items: 'li:not(.ui-tabs-nav-item,#newspod,#imglist li)', containment: '#sortable'})

$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add this property

```
distance: 15
```

to your sortable object so that the user has to drag it 15 pixels before it will activate the sortable behavior.

Comment: Ok thanks .. but is that the right syntax? It seems to be breaking my javascript.

EDIT: Nevermind -- I got it, but it still doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: When I click and drag the scrollbar inside the div, the div gets locked to the cursor and becomes sortable. I just want it to stay in place while I'm scrolling inside the div